# IO Language How to create a list that has randomly generated values?

Tags: iolanguage

I am doing a project for my programming languages class. This one is on the IO Language. My question is is it possible to randomly generate values into an empty cloned list? I've been searching their homepage, but can't find the info I am looking for. If anyone has knowledge on this language and could help that'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
GenerateRandomList := method(n,
    newList := list()
    n repeat(
        newList push(Random value)
    )
    newList
)
```